# MongoDB 3.0 Windows Service Start : System Error 2 has occured

Tags: mongodb, windows-services

I have downloaded the MongoDB Windows msi install and run this successfully.

The mongod.exe and mongo.exe command file executions work properly.

The installation manual shows how to create the configuration file, and then to create the Windows Server using the command

```
sc.exe create MongoDB binPath= "\"C:\mongodb\mongod.exe\" --service --config=\"C:\mongodb\mongod.cfg\""
```

This creates a SUCCESS response.

The service is then started

```
net start MongoDB
```

but this produces the response

```
System Error 2 has occurred.
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

The resolution, for those who need this, is that the manual indicates the incorrect default path for mongod.exe, which should be in the bin directory

```
C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe
```

Thus, whereas this is a question, I have also solved this for the benefit of others who may have this problem.

Also, by default, MongoDB will install in C:\Program Files in Windows, and you should use the custom install to put it into C:\mongodb.

Comment: I disagree that this is a duplicate. My issue is that the default implementation and the manual are not in sync. This is not covered in the cited question or its answers.

Answer (score 4):

It can be possible that you already have a service named "MongoDB" before your installation and thus it is not successfully installed.

try to remove the previous one using this:
`"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin\mongod.exe" --remove`

and then you can try install the service again and fire the `net start MongoDB` command. It should work now.

Comment: please add `--serviceName=<YOUR SERVICE NAME>` if the default service name `MongoDB` is not used.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced this problem.And I solved as below.

1) Create this folders

```
C:\data\db
C:\data\log
```

2)Run CMD as administrator

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
```

3)If you've installed service , write below to cmd to remove

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin> mongod.exe --remove
```

4) This is important , I don't use `sc.exe`  Determine the log and db directory ,and instal service

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin> mongod.exe --logpath c:\data\log\mongod.log --dbpath c:\data\db --directoryperdb --install
```

5)If success

```
net start MongoDB
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After having installed mongodb in `C:\mongodb` you just do:

```
mongod --install --logpath C:\mongodb\logs\mongo.log
```

The path to the logfile must exist and it must be an absolute Windows path. Then you start the MongoDB service by typing:

```
net start MongoDB
```